# Why does a wind turbine deliver reactive power to the grid during no winds or when turbine is stopped?

Tags: power-electronics, electricity, electrical, electric-machine, power-grid

An answer to a [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/384299/why-does-a-turbine-with-pmsg-and-full-converter-system-draws-reactive-power-when) explained that a turbine in stop mode may deliver reactive power to the grid. It also takes active power from the grid to run its control system, lighting system and some other functions. I don't understand why it delivers reactive power to the grid when it is taking active power from it? What is the purpose for that?

Comment: I would suggest you the renewable energy MOOC by Delft university on edX, it consists of 4-5 parts or modules and i would say covers everything in renewable

Comment: Basically a duplicate of : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/384299/152903

Comment: @Solar mike Not a duplicate actually. I at first thought we take reactive power from grid as mentioned in the question because the values on our scada system were negative and turbine was stopped. But then somebody mentioned we actually deliver it to the grid. So now my question is 'why we deliver it'?

Comment: Well you need to study in detail energy generation and power factor analysis and power factor correction - I had fun doing the calcs for a wind turbine to specify a capacitor bank that switched in or out as appropriate then spending the money ordering it...

Comment: @solar mike can you suggest me some specific books? There are some very basic concepts that I am not able to undertsand. And if u have an answer for the above question then please answer it

Comment: @Jason - it is a duplicate.  You don't get to repost on the same topic just because your initial post had errors.  Edit your initial post to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a turbine with PMSG and full converter system draws reactive power when turbine is stopped or there is no wind?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/384299/why-does-a-turbine-with-pmsg-and-full-converter-system-draws-reactive-power-when)

Comment: I didnt see the answer in the comment section in my previous question given in the link by solar and chris. I am new to this site so quite unfamiliar with how it works. Anyways, i tried to delete or merge the question with the other but there is no option

Comment: Your existing question has an edit button, use that to improve it.  And this one *should* have a delete button, but even if it doesn't, you can still fix the original.

Comment: @Chris Stratton I think this is a legitimate follow-up to the original question. It seems to me that when an answer motivates the asker to answer another question along the same lines, expanding the question is rather like starting a discussion.

Answer (score 4):

Wind turbine generators follow specific rules for operation called "grid code". The transmission system operator (TSO) imposes some requirements through these grid codes that all grid-connected wind turbine generators (WTGs) should follow when they are connected to the grid.

In general, reactive power regulation required from wind turbine generators are based on wind farm (WF)/wind turbine capacity, grid voltage level and grid stiffness. In general, WTG reactive power control may follow one of following three modes.

1) Reactive power control mode: TSO asks WTG/WF operator to provide specific amount of reactive power.

2) Power factor control mode: TSO asks WTG/WF operator to provide reactive power with respect to active power generated by WTG/WF.

3) Voltage control mode: TSO asks WTG/WF operator to provide reactive power to the grid as a function of PCC (point of common connection) voltage.

Now if WTG/WF works in first or third mode, it should provide reactive power to grid if that is the requirement from TSO regardless active power generation (If that is the grid code requirement).

The purpose of this from TSO point of view is to regulate the grid voltage by supplying/consuming reactive power from WTG/WF as it is done by conventional power plants.